# Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. when loading blazor app

Tags: c#, iis, blazor, webdeploy

I am trying to deploy a blazor app to a iis server and the deploy is successful but
I am getting the following error when I am trying to load a blazor app that I made in a web page:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.



Detailed Error Information:



Module
   IIS Web Core 

Notification
   BeginRequest 

Handler
   Not yet determined 

Error Code
   0x8007000d 

Config Error
    

Config File
   \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TS\surplus\web.config 



Requested URL
   https://localhost:443/TS/surplus/ 

Physical Path
   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TS\surplus\ 

Logon Method
   Not yet determined 

Logon User
   Not yet determined 




Config Source:
   -1: 
    0: 




More Information:
This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error. 
View more information »
```

I did a bunch of google searching and from what I gathered it might be a issue with my web.config so here is my web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\Surplus.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 4a9f1694-7809-44be-b748-df9789a82b33-->
```

any help would be amazing!!!!!